# How to add tooltip for ngSelect options ? On hovering the options in the dropdown i need to show tooltip

Tags: angular

```
    <ng-select [items]="cities"
               bindLabel="name"
               placeholder="Select city"
               [(ngModel)]="selectedCity">
    </ng-select>
```

How to add tooltip for ngSelect options ? On hovering the options in the dropdown i need to show tooltip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [templates](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/templates) for options, and in those template you can add a tooltip.

In below example, I have used HTML attribute `title` to show tooltip, if you are using library like ng-bootstrap, then, you can use tooltip capability from that library.

```
<ng-select [items]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" bindLabel="name" bindValue="name">
    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-index="index" let-search="searchTerm">
       <span title="A sample info in tooltip">{{item.name}}</span>
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. What if we need to show the title for a selected item?